# Option elements in JSF / Rich Faces

Tags: jsp, jsf, jakarta-ee, richfaces

Doing a RichFaces/jsf project in a new job, haven't been doing it long.

The main page has a xhtml page that has a frameset. In an ideal world it wouldn't have but it has and it needs to stay that way, but when you log in as a certain level of user, the side frames aren't used.

```
<frameset cols="#{Base.sideBars['left'].width},*,#{Base.sideBars['right'].width}" id="contentframes" >
<frame name="left" src="left.jsf" id="leftframe"/>
<frame name="center" src="center.jsf" id="centerframe" />
<frame name="right" src="right.jsf" id="rightframe" />
</frameset>
```

is there a 'native' way of changing this so that I just include the center frame, or is it just easier to change it to a jsp and put an if / else around it?

What I need is the resultant html that is like this:

```
<frameset cols="20,*,20" id="contentframes" >
<frame name="left" src="left.jsf" id="leftframe"/>
<frame name="center" src="center.jsf" id="centerframe" />
<frame name="right" src="right.jsf" id="rightframe" />
</frameset>
```

when you log in as one user, but if the other user logs in, you just include the elements that were in centerframe.jsf without any frames at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if else would be better. or even you can manage it by

```
<frame name="center" src="#{someBean.centerPage}.jsf" id="centerframe" />
```

Comment: Not sure what you mean - that is still a frame, I need to get rid of the frameset. I have amended the question in case it is not clear

Comment: well what I answered is you want to dynamically insert frames, for that there are two ways first if .. else conditionally insert or use the value of bean to evalute the target page

Comment: Sorry for my lack of clarity, have now ammended it. I want to have no frames (or I guess maybe a frameset of one I suppose) if the other user logs in. I need to kill left and right frames.

Comment: then you can just put conditional stuff.. or even better go for facelets

Comment: Not too much detail but with your page link in your answer it occured to me that I can just do a UI include with details from a bean on the filename of the page that has the frames, or the page that doesn't, So even though it isn't actually the answer it helped me find it, thanks

Answer (score 1):

Client-side includes like framesets aren't terribly useful when you're already using a server-side view technology. They're not only bad for user experience and SEO, but they allows very little fine-grained control from the server side on. You should instead use server-side includes. In JSF you can use the `rendered` attribute to display content conditionally.

```
<h:panelGroup id="left" layout="block" rendered="#{user.hasRole('ADMIN')}">
    <ui:include src="left.xhtml" />
</h:panelGroup>
<h:panelGroup id="center" layout="block">
    <ui:include src="center.xhtml" />
</h:panelGroup>
<h:panelGroup id="right" layout="block" rendered="#{user.hasRole('ADMIN')}">
    <ui:include src="right.xhtml" />
</h:panelGroup>
```

This will render as follows when the user has the role "ADMIN":

```
<div id="left">
    left.xhtml content
</div>
<div id="center">
    center.xhtml content
</div>
<div id="right">
    right.xhtml content
</div>
```

And as follows if the user doesn't has the role "ADMIN":

```
<div id="center">
    center.xhtml content
</div>
```

You can use CSS to position and float the `<div>` elements.

Comment: As I said in the question, it has frames and it needs to stay that way. I realise it is not ideal for user experience (SEO doesn't matter at all), which is why I said I wish it didn't! However, useful info so I will mark it up